Compute uniformly distributed n-th random number in range
I need to quickly compute uniformly distributed n-th pseudo-random number in range [a, b] without storing any state information.
I.e., computation should depend only on n, and [a, b] (and possibly seed) input parameters and should not keep any internal state.
The quality of the randomness does not need to be good.
How can I do it?
Need to do it on the fly. Pre-computing random numbers and storing them in the lookup table is not what I want.

Which programming language do you use?

@Reporter c++ (20)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift

What do you mean by "n-th pseudo-random number"? Pretend that you have generated n-1 other numbers in that range?

@Caleth Pretend that I computed N random numbers (N is large) the usual way, stored them in lut[N], and now I compute n-th random number via taking value of lut[n]
So computation is "determenistic" in a sense that multiple accesses to lut[n] return the same n-th random value

"The quality of the randomness does not need to be good." In this case, return (a+b)/2;" fits the bill

n is the state you're looking for :) Well, after you pass it through a function. That function can be a hash. The state is then passed as a seed to an instance of a random number generator. So n->hash->state->seed->random sample. For each n, a new random generator state is devised. If you want to "open up" the source of the random generator, it can be made a bit more efficient than with the standard library API. But, in general, that'd be the idea. Easy to implement.

Are you looking for the n-th order statistic from a set of N random numbers? Or are you trying to maintain synchronization between two pseudo-random number streams having the same initial seed? Your question seems quite ambiguous to me, perhaps letting us know what the application goal is would help.

You still haven’t explained exactly what you mean. If you mean simply the nth number drawn out of a hat then that has precisely the same distribution as everything else … so you don’t even need to draw the others. On the other hand, if you want the nth smallest out of N randomly drawn IID variables then that is an interesting problem: the quartiles and median, for example, are important statistics.

The standard library pseudorandom number engines have a member function discard, which advances it's state as-if it were called n times.
template <typename Seed>
int generate_nth_uniform_int(int n, int a, int b, Seed&& seed) {
    std::mt19937 gen(std::forward<Seed>(seed));
    if (n > 0)
        gen.discard(n-1);
    return std::uniform_int_distribution(a, b)(gen);
}


Is there a guarantee that discard's complexity is constant? Otherwise, this turns into an O(N^2) generator...

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica No there isn't.

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica It's up-to amortized linear, but is encouraged to be faster than that

One possible way is to use one of the various CRC functions. You'd have to pick a function that fits the data range. A CRC-32 is not going to cut it with a 64-bit range and a CRC-16 is not going to work with a 32-bit range.
